# How to serialize 2 models with custom relationship in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 existing tables in database and i haven't permission to alter them. Show as models below.

```
class Prenames(models.Model):
    typ = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=0, db_column='tprpretyp')
    code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, db_column='tprprecod')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column='tprprenam')

class Profiles(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=6, db_column='rmsuserid')
    prename = models.CharField(max_length=4, db_column='rmsprenam', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column='rmsname')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column='rmssurnam')
```

If sql i have to

```
SELECT * FROM Profiles left join Prenames on tprpretyp = int(rmsprenam/1000) and tprprecod = mod(rmsprenam,1000) WHERE trim(rmsuserid) = ?
```

Things I've already try:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class PrenameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Prenames
        fields = ('type', 'code', 'name')


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prenames = PrenameSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('userid', 'name', 'surname', 'prenames')
```

Things I've got:

```
{
  "userid": "560174",
  "name": "******",
  "surname": "******"
}
```

Things I expected:

```
{
  "userid": "560174",
  "name": "******",
  "surname": "******"
  "prenames":[
      {
          "type:":10,
          "code": 01,
          "name": "Mr."
      }
  ]
}
```

I'm using django-rest-framework 3.2.5 and django 1.6 how do i serialize them?

Comment: `prenames = PrenameSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)` . Try this to get all the prenames by using the many=True argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
prenames = PrenameSerializer(source="how_you_get_this_field, many=True, read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Aison for giving me an inspiration.
This solution is not exactly what I want. But it save my life for now.
From [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). I decided to modify ProfileSerializer to

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prenameth = serializers.SerializerMethodField('getprenameth')
    prenameen = serializers.SerializerMethodField('getprenameen')

    def getprenameth(self, obj):
        return obj.prename.name

    def getprenameen(self, obj):
        return obj.prename.en_pre_name

    class Meta:
        model = Patients
        fields = ('userid', 'name', 'surname', 'prenames', 'prenameth', 'prenameen')
```

And this what I got from it.

```
{
  "userid": "560174",
  "name": "******",
  "surname": "******",
  "prenameth": "นาย",
  "prenameen": "Mr."
}
```

This is enough for now.

Comment: I should told you about serializermethodfield.Sorry for I don't have time to edit my answer(I'm at the wedding now) Anyway, glad to know you figure it out.